# Array of products arrange by category

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, mapping

I'm trying to arrange this array of products by categories. For now, I get the count of each category but I can't figure out how to make this two dimension array output.

```
let products = [
  {name: 'Tequila', category: 'drink'}, 
  {name: 'Beer', category: 'drink'}, 
  {name: 'Burger', category: 'food'},
  {name: 'Shawarma', category: 'food'}, 
  {name: 'Wine', category: 'drink'},
  {name: 'Gelatto', category: 'dessert'}
];

/*expected ouput

let arranged = [[
  {name: 'Tequila', category: 'drink'}, 
  {name: 'Beer', category: 'drink'},
  {name: 'Wine', category: 'drink'}
], [
  {name: 'Burger', category: 'food'},
  {name: 'Shawarma', category: 'food'}
], [
  {name: 'Gelatto', category: 'dessert'}
]];

*/
```

This is my code for now:

```js
let products = [
  {name: 'Tequila', category: 'drink'}, 
  {name: 'Beer', category: 'drink'}, 
  {name: 'Burger', category: 'food'},
  {name: 'Shawarma', category: 'food'}, 
  {name: 'Wine', category: 'drink'},
  {name: 'Gelatto', category: 'dessert'}
];

let arranged = {};

products.map(x => arranged[x.category] = 1 + (arranged[x.category] || 0));

console.log(arranged);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.I am using [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to group the objects in array by category key ,then you can get the required data with `Object.values()`

```js
let products = [{
    name: 'Tequila',
    category: 'drink'
  },
  {
    name: 'Beer',
    category: 'drink'
  },
  {
    name: 'Burger',
    category: 'food'
  },
  {
    name: 'Shawarma',
    category: 'food'
  },
  {
    name: 'Wine',
    category: 'drink'
  },
  {
    name: 'Gelatto',
    category: 'dessert'
  }
];



let group = products.reduce((r, a) => {


  r[a.category] = [...r[a.category] || [], a];
  return r;
}, {});
console.log(Object.values(group));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can group elements by reducing over the array using an object to store elements belonging to each category. To get the grouped categories, we can use `Object.values`.

```js
let products = [{name: 'Tequila', category: 'drink'}, 
{name: 'Beer', category: 'drink'}, 
{name: 'Burger', category: 'food'},
{name: 'Shawarma', category: 'food'}, 
{name: 'Wine', category: 'drink'},
{name: 'Gelatto', category: 'dessert'}];
const res = Object.values(
  products.reduce((acc,curr)=>(
    (acc[curr.category] = acc[curr.category] || []).push(curr), acc
  ), {})
);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thank you!, this works, Object.values throws me an error in Angular, is there a way to use Object.keys instead?

Comment: @sonEtLumiere You can try `let obj = products.reduce(/*...*/); let res = Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key]);`.

Answer (score 1):

I use reducer to go over the array. For builing the groups I use an index-array where I store the category. Before adding a new item I look if in this array exists the category. If so I take the index and just add to this index-th group the item. Otherwise I create a new grup-array to which I add the item.

```js
let products = [{name: 'Tequila', category: 'drink'}, 
{name: 'Beer', category: 'drink'}, 
{name: 'Burger', category: 'food'},
{name: 'Shawarma', category: 'food'}, 
{name: 'Wine', category: 'drink'},
{name: 'Gelatto', category: 'dessert'}];

let categories=[];
let res = products.reduce((new_object, current_item) => {
    index = categories.indexOf(current_item.category);

    if (index==-1) {
        categories.push(current_item.category)
        new_object.push([current_item]);
    } else {
        new_object[index].push(current_item);
    }
    return new_object;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Opt for [`Object.groupBy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/groupBy) combined with [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) for a streamlined and organized data structure.

```js
const products = [
  {name: 'Tequila', category: 'drink'}, 
  {name: 'Beer', category: 'drink'}, 
  {name: 'Burger', category: 'food'},
  {name: 'Shawarma', category: 'food'}, 
  {name: 'Wine', category: 'drink'},
  {name: 'Gelatto', category: 'dessert'}
];

const categoryArray = Object.groupBy(products, ({ category }) => category)
console.log(Object.values(categoryArray));
```